# Prove that a matrix is equal to another

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

So for my linear algebra and differential equations, our professor gave us a problem to work on over the weekend. I have been able to solve this problem multiple times by using any values for $a,b,c,d$, but I have no clue how to prove it using the variables.

The statement is, prove that if
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$
then
$$ A^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det{A}}
\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}$$

The only clue that he gave me when I messaged him about it was to use the adjoint method, but from my understanding that is just the matrix flipped and negated which is the result. How do I prove this?

Comment: What do you get if you compute the product $$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Why not simply calculate $A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: multiply them together, and use the fact that $\det(A)=ad-bc$

I'd write something like this:
Let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$$
And
$$B= \frac{1}{\det{A}}
\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}$$
Then
$$AB=\dots=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=I$$
So by definition, we have that
$$A^{-1}=B=\frac{1}{\det{A}}
\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: When I multiply the two matrixes together I get \begin{bmatrix}ad-bc&0\\0&ad-bc\end{bmatrix}
I can see that the det(A) = a*d-b*c but how does that relate to the multiplied matrix?

Comment: @97WaterPolo Do you know how does scalar-mateix multiplication work?

Comment: $$ \frac{1}{ad-bc}
\begin{bmatrix}ad-bc&0\\0&ad-bc\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}(ad-bc)/(ad-bc)&0\\0&(ad-bc)/(ad-bc)\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} $$

which is the identity matrix, and the Thm states that A*A^-1 = I therefore (i don't know how to put it all together)

Comment: @97WaterPolo Good job, you are done with the proof!

Comment: @97WaterPolo What would you like to put together?

Comment: My question is how do I put the final statement together to sum up all the work I did? I attached a [photo here of the work](http://siglerdev.us/img/math.png) on paper with a therefore statement at the end, is it correct?

Comment: @97WaterPolo I added to the answer the way I'd write it, but you don't need to write this exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't exactly sure how to structure the final statement, I understood how it correlated but didn't know how to sum it up. Much appreciated for working through it with me!

Comment: @97WaterPolo I'm glad I was able to help.